# Difference in way French Characters are displayed between environments

Tags: 2013, multilingual

We have two SharePoint 2013 environments (DEV and UAT) and there are differences in the way French characters are displayed between the environments.  In the image below the top is from DEV where French characters are displayed correctly, and the bottom is from UAT where French characters are displayed as a question mark inside a diamond.

[image]

Things to note:

The Site Collection from DEV is backed up and restored into UAT so I don't know that there would be any configuration difference or anything "inside" the content database.

We checked the SQL collation on the content database in both environments and it is `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS.`

What could be causing this?

Comment: In which language SharePoint installed? english or french?

Comment: I believe it was installed in English, any way to check?  I forgot to mention we are using Variations and these pages are under the French label which uses Language = French (France) and Locale = French (Canada)

Comment: on both farm do you have French language packs installed? make Sure it is on UAT..

Comment: I've asked the ops team to confirm, but I would assume yes since I was able to create a variation label for French, create the hierarchies, and see propagation working.  I'm also able to create French labels form terms in the term store.